How to handle polymorphic event types in C# with a base class and derived classes?
I'm trying to implement polymorphism in C# for handling various event types with a single ProcessEvent method. Here's an example of my current setup:
public class BaseProposedEvent
{
    public required string EventType { get; set; }
}

public class ProposeTeamCreatedEvent : BaseProposedEvent
{
    public required string TeamName { get; set; }
}

I want to pass instances of derived classes (like ProposeTeamCreatedEvent) to ProcessEvent while declaring the parameter as BaseProposedEvent. However, since TeamName is not a property of the base class, I can't directly access it within the method. For example:
public void ProcessEvent(BaseProposedEvent proposedEvent)
{
    // I can't access `TeamName` if the event is not a `ProposeTeamCreatedEvent`.
}

One workaround I thought of is passing a JSON string and an event type to ProcessEvent, but this approach gets messy as it requires serialization/deserialization on both the server and client sides.
In TypeScript, this problem is easily managed with type unions and discriminated unions:
export type IncomingMessage =
  | IAuthMessage
  | IProposeEventMessage
  | IProposeEndGameMessage
  | IHeartBeatMessage;

export interface IAuthMessage {
  type: "auth";
  gameId: string;
  userToken: string;
}

How can I achieve a similar level of flexibility in C# without resorting to manual JSON handling? Is there a better approach to work with polymorphic event types in a clean and type-safe manner?
Also note that is part of an application using SignalR. The hub would look like this:
public async Task ProposeEvent(int gameId, string userToken, string eventType, BaseProposedEvent proposedEvent)
        {
            // todo: eventId should be set on client, no?
            var gameState = gameStateService.GetGameState(gameId);
            if (gameState is null)
            {
                logger.LogWarning("User {userToken} tried to join game {gameId}. The game does not exist", userToken, gameId);
                throw new HubException("Game does not exist.");
            }

            if (!gameState.IsUserInGame(userToken))
            {
                logger.LogWarning("User {userToken} tried invoking JoinGame before joining via API", userToken);
                throw new HubException("You must join the game via the API before connecting.");
            }

            if (!gameState.IsGameAdmin(userToken))
            {
                logger.LogWarning("User {userToken} is not the admin of game {gameId}. The user may not propose an event.", userToken, gameId);
                throw new HubException("Only the admin may perform actions in this game.");
            }

            var processEventResult = await eventProcessor.ProcessEventAsync(proposedEvent, eventType, gameId, userToken, gameState);
            if (processEventResult.IsFailure)
            {
                logger.LogCritical("The proposed event was invalid. Event type: {eventType}", eventType);
                throw new HubException($"The proposed event was invalid. Event type: {eventType}.");
            }

            gameStateService.UpdateGameState(gameId, processEventResult.Value.UpdatedGameState);
            await Clients.Group(GameUtility.GetGameIdString(gameId)).SendGameEvent(processEventResult.Value);
            logger.LogInformation(
                "State updated for game {gameId}. The event was processed successfully. Event type: {eventType}",
                gameId,
                eventType
            );
        }
    ```

I added `eventType` as an argument to `ProcessEvent` to help when narrowing the type of the `BaseEvent`.

